# wpf datagrid CellEditEnding doesn't fire after checkbox click

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Why does `CellEditEnding / RowEditEnding` doesn't fire?
This is my code for `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Double " 
            Binding="{Binding DoubleBonus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                 </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="Bold" />
                 </Style>
             </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

and this is my code for DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridSpeciel"  Height="183" CanUserAddRows="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="8,0,3,10.2" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFD4B4B4" RowBackground="#FFBFD4E8" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" SelectionMode="Single" RowEditEnding="dataGridSpeciel_RowEditEnding" CellEditEnding="dataGridSpeciel_CellEditEnding" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="dataGridSpeciel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

Comment: These events are fired with Text and CheckBoxColumns . Some more code can help you.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan
What do you mean some more code?

Comment: Your present XAML doesnt help much, post some relevant c# code. These events are fired in my case.